# Could not get current Location from CLLocationManager

Tags: swift, core-location

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    private var onLocation: ((CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Void)?
    private let manager: CLLocationManager
    
    override init() {
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        super.init()
        
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
    }
    
    public func getLocation(_ onLocation: ((CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Void)?) {
        self.onLocation = onLocation
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(#function, locations)
        guard let currentCoordinate = manager.location?.coordinate else {return}
        onLocation?(currentCoordinate)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(#function, error)
    }
    
}
```

this code is not calling didUpdateLocation or didFailWithError. can anyone tell me what could be the problem here?

```
LocationManager().getLocation { coordinate in
    print(#function, coordinate)
}
```

this is how i am calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain the `let manager = CLLocationManager()` in your class as a property. Otherwise, it will be deallocated at the end of that function and hence none of its delegate methods will be called at all.

**UPDATED**

Another issue is the following code where you call `getLocation`. You need to retain `LocationManager()` in your client class otherwise the `LocationManager` will be deallocated at the end of that function.

```
private let locationManager = LocationManager()

locationManager.getLocation { coordinate in
    print(#function, coordinate)
}
```

Comment: i updated the question so you can check i have tried both

Comment: Hi @sahib. I just updated my answer. Please try and let me know